# Is the squeal a manifestation of the Painleve Paradox?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, acoustics, friction

When a DJ does a rewind (suddenly reverses the direction of the vinyl’s rotation under the needle), a sharp squeal is produced. This squeal is neither simply the music played backwards (as a film would be when viewed backwards) nor is it due to a higher pitch because of acceleration…it must be something else.

In mechanics there is something called a [Painlevé Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Painlev%C3%A9_paradox) and I think it might also produce the squeal. The P-Paradox arises, for example, when one pushes (not pulls) a chalk across the blackboard. It screeches and jumps a bit up and down instead of drawing a smooth line. The reason is that the angle between the chalk and the blackboard is 'oblique' (instead of perpendicular or 'acute').

I think the angle between the needle and the vinyl may also be a bit oblique when played backwards and that this may be why a Painlevé Paradox occurs during a rewind.

Any thoughts to the question:
Is the squeal a manifestation of the Painleve Paradox ?

Comment: You should ask a definitive question. Questions that are opinion based usually get closed on this site.

Comment: the question is: is the squeal a manifestation of the Painleve Paradox

Comment: are you sure it is not an artifact of the discontinuity introduced in the sound wave when the wheel stops before changing direction?

Comment: yes, that could also be an explanation... But since I'm not sure, I'd like to hear more opinions